# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured each time running pytest

Tags: python-3.x, django, pytest-django

Whenever I open my django project and try to test it I get  `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`
Or it can be other explanation with the same Error (not always with INSTALLED_APPS...).

I can fix it with command:
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<project_name>.settings

But I would have to do it every time I open the project. Is there a way for this to be fixed once and forever?

Comment: Have you installed `pytest-django` and followed the docs https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?

Comment: I have installed both ```pytest``` and ```django-pytest```.

Comment: Did you create a `pytest.ini` file like the docs suggest?

Comment: I tried, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: What command are you running, where are you running it from, what does your `pytest.ini` contain and where is your `pytest.ini` located? Adding the full traceback from the error may help too